# Is there a way to restore specific table/column data without a backup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, database-restore

I accidentally updated 2 columns across all rows in a table. Is there any way to revert the data? I dont have an archive of this table.

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck, if there is no backup... SQL Server will not keep these *old values* somewhere for you... Don't know which system you are running, but there is a tiny chance, that your OS allows to grab a *previous version*. But - to be honest - I doubt this will help you...

Comment: i used ms sql server 2008 R2

Comment: No, I meant the OS (it's `Windows` probably...)  A right click on a file allows you to open a properties dialog. If this is configured, you might find a tab with previous versions... But I doubt, that this is configured in your case...

Comment: Sorry. Where i can find the 'file'? I only have access via Object Explorer.

Comment: The properties of your table show you details about the files involved...

Comment: If your DB is in full recovery mode I think it can be backed up from transaction log. You will need some last backup and restore to some point in time in transaction log.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have full recovery mode.